# Include Calculator activity inside a Sherlock fragment

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

Hi I'm working on a launcher for education and I have a calculator activity and xml layout file I want to include in the fragmenttab2 I am using the include layout in the xml and it shows up fine but when I click a button say the number 3 the app crashes what am I doing wrong?

fragmenttab2.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg" >

    <include
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        layout="@layout/activity_calculator" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/app"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/allapps" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/tools"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/tools" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/web"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/internet" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Calculator Buttons:

```
button0=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button0);
        button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.engery);
        button2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.heatcal);
        button3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.tempcal);
        button4=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);

        button5=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button5);
        button6=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button6);
        button7=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button7);
        button8=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button8);
        button9=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button9);

        buttonPlus=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonPlus);
        buttonMinus=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonMinus);
        buttonMultiply=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonMultiply);
        buttonDivide=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonDivide);
        buttonPoint=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonPoint);

        buttonEqual=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonEqual);



        vibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE); 
        //button_del=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_del)
```

;

[image]

LogCat:

```
09-22 00:18:53.036: D/AndroidRuntime(1578): Shutting down VM
09-22 00:18:53.036: W/dalvikvm(1578): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
09-22 00:18:53.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1578): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-22 00:18:53.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1578): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method onClickListener7(View) in the activity class com.d4a.stzh.MainActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'button7'
09-22 00:18:53.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1578):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3586)
09-22 00:18:53.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1578):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
09-22 00:18:53.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1578):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
09-22 00:18:53.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1578):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
09-22 00:18:53.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1578):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-22 00:18:53.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1578):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-22 00:18:53.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1578):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
09-22 00:18:53.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1578):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-22 00:18:53.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1578):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-22 00:18:53.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1578):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
09-22 00:18:53.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1578):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
09-22 00:18:53.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1578):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-22 00:18:53.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1578): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: onClickListener7 [class android.view.View]
09-22 00:18:53.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1578):     at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:460)
09-22 00:18:53.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1578):     at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:915)
09-22 00:18:53.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1578):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3579)
09-22 00:18:53.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1578):
```

any help would Be amazing i'm still new to android so please don't judge

Rapsong11

Comment: inside of eclipse find the logcat window. When you app crashes there should be a bunch of red text inside there that explains what exception caused your crash. Edit your question and add this exception text.

Comment: added Logcat to the description

Answer (score 0):

it's about your "`button7.setOnClickListener()`". you can check your button7 definition, like this;

```
button_name = (Button) findviewbyId(R.id.button7);
```

and you should add clicklistener after the definition.
By the way, if you want to define & use any view in your activity, first you should load required xml file. Using "`setContentView();`"

that is just an assumption, because i need to view your codes.

and maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6388070/1763249) can help you.

Comment: I mean, you should add clicklistener part with definitions or all of them.